# How can I build a complex e-mail - template plus content saved in a variable - using cfscript instead of cfmail?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

This is expanding a bit on a question I asked earlier.  Server is CF2016.  I'm saving a table of data using savecontent:

```
savecontent variable = 'mailBody' {
   writeOutput('
    <table width="99%" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:99%;">
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color:##09AFFF;color:##FFFFFF;width:30%;padding-left:3px;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;font-size:12px;font-weight:700;border-bottom:1px solid ##5B5B5B;text-align:left;">Name</td>
        <td style="background-color:##09AFFF;color:##FFFFFF;width:15%;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;font-size:12px;font-weight:700;border-bottom:1px solid ##5B5B5B;text-align:center;">Class</td>
        <td style="background-color:##09AFFF;color:##FFFFFF;width:30%;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;font-size:12px;text-align:left;font-weight:700;border-bottom:1px solid ##5B5B5B;">City,State,ZIP</td>
        <td style="background-color:##09AFFF;color:##FFFFFF;width:15%;padding-right:5px;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;font-size:12px;text-align:left;font-weight:700;border-bottom:1px solid ##5B5B5B;">Amount</td>
      </tr>
  ');

   for ( qryPeople in queryPeople ){
       writeOutput('
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size:12px;padding-left:3px;padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:4px;background-color:#thisBgColor#;border-bottom:1px solid ##5B5B5B;">#qryPeople.p_first# #qryPeople.p_last#</td>
        <td style="font-size:12px;padding-left:3px;padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:4px;background-color:#thisBgColor#;border-bottom:1px solid ##5B5B5B;text-align:center;">#YEAR(qryPeople.p_graduation)#</td>
        <td style="font-size:12px;padding-left:3px;padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:4px;background-color:#thisBgColor#;border-bottom:1px solid ##5B5B5B;">#qryPeople.p_city# #qryPeople.p_state#</td>
        <td style="font-size:12px;padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:4px;padding-right:5px;background-color:#thisBgColor#;border-bottom:1px solid ##5B5B5B;">#NumberFormat(qryValue.p_value,'99,999')#</td>
      </tr>
    ');
   };
   writeOutput('
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="font-size:11px;padding-left:5px;padding-top:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-bottom:7px;background-color:##09AFFF;color:##FFFFFF;font-style:italic;border-bottom:1px solid ##5B5B5B;">footer text</td> 
      </tr>  
    </table>
  '); 
};//end savecontent
```

Works fine through here - I can output the variable mailBody and I see a styled table suitable for HTML email.

We have stock email templates that we use (.htm) files that are stored centrally.  I'm trying to inject this content into one of these templates to be sent.

```
    mailerService = new mail();
    mailTemplate = fileRead(application.paths.physicalroot & '\email\project1\templates\people.htm');
    mailerService.setTo("me@domain.com"); 
    mailerService.setFrom("support@domain.com"); 
    mailerService.setSubject("People Report"); 
    mailerService.setType("html"); 
    mailerService.send(body=mailTemplate);
```

In the .htm template file I have

```
<cfoutput>#mailBody#</cfoutput>
```

And it's giving me exactly that - #mailBody#.  In less complex e-mails I have no problem using something like

```
<cfoutput>Welcome #qryPeople.p_first# #qryPeople.p_last#</cfoutput>
```

Or accessing other variables set on the cfscript template that drives the e-mail.  But I can't figure out why my savecontent variable isn't working as expected.

SOLUTION - previously trying a savecontent include did not work, but that may have been on ACF 2010.  This works on ACF2016.

```
mailerService = new mail();
savecontent variable="mailTemplate" {
  include variables.templatePath & '\email\project1\templates\people.htm';
};
mailerService.setTo("me@domain.com");
```

People.htm is included and the other savecontent (mailbody) is rendered in the e-mail.  Now to figure it out using the newer cfmail() script...

Comment: Please verify that if you replace the savecontent part with `mailBody = 'ColdFusion Variable';` that your .htm file will output the value of the variable.

Comment: Any particular version of CF?

Comment: We are running ACF 2016.

Comment: Just *reading* in a file containing CFML code won't execute that code. You either need to 1) use `evaulate()` to force the code *within* the variable to be evaluated . It's one of the few legitimate uses of evaluate().  OR 2) use placeholders in your templates, then `replace()` them with the dynamic mailbody string.  Keep in mind using `evaluate()` is NOT at all security conscious. It does what you tell it. So using it on client supplied or arbitrary content carries some risks.

Comment: Ooopha.  Or just bust out of script and build the mail in tags which works perfectly.

Comment: Of course, but then what's the purpose of this "template" you mentioned?

Comment: @Ageax, I didn't see anything in the question about reading a file containing CF code, but if that is the scenario there is another way to get that code to execute.  Include the file.

Comment: @Ageax a simple include in a savecontent worked, which is odd because I had problems doing that before previously (thought that may have been ACF2010).

Comment: @DanBracuk and Steve - Using an include makes sense. That would force an evaluation (which would work since the variable used in the cfoutput is declared beforehand). I usually go the "replace" route so I wasn't thinking that would work, but good to know it does :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have one "block" to be evaluated, I'd just replace it using a string function:

```
mailTemplate = fileRead(application.paths.physicalroot & '\email\project1\templates\people.htm');
mailTemplate = replaceNoCase(mailTemplate, "##mailBody##", mailBody, "one");
// continue with mailerService.* methods
```

Another option is to use include with a saveContent:

This may require that you rename your template from a *.htm to be *.cfm file.

```
// create mailBody first using your current saveContent
savecontent variable="finalBody" {
    include "#application.paths.physicalroot#\email\project1\templates\people.cfm";
}
```

The variable finalBody should now contain the content from the mailBody variable.

Comment: the include worked (though your code isn't correct) - there is no template = "" - it's just include "path/to/file/file.htm";  (or at least your code through an error on ACF2016)

Comment: @steve, yep Sublime usually adds attributes like that.  It's either a hold-over from the tag format or supporting CF2018 which I think has parameterized the scripting functions.  It is odd that location can take url="", etc. but include doesn't.  I like script, but it still isn't consistent in 2016 (which I primarily use).  Glad that you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you can have CF markup in the templates you should be able to get the results you want with this:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="mailBody">
<cfinclude template="#application.paths.physicalroot#\email\project1\templates\people.htm"> 
</cfsavecontent>
```